# Calculating Conditional Expectations

Tags: probability, expected-value, continuous-data

Say $X$ is continuous and distributed according to [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) $G$.

How would we calculate $\text{E}[X|X<a]$?

Comment: The conditional mean equals $\frac{E(X\mathbf1_{X<a})}{P(X<a)}$.

Comment: This is only true, if $P(X<a) = G(a-) > 0$. Is that the case?

Comment: What is $E(X1_{X<a})$?  And what does $G(a-)$ mean?

Comment: It is indeed the case that $P(X<a)>0$

Comment: @Guest Is this for some course? Can you find the conditional (truncated) distribution $X\mid X<a$ and hence find the expectation?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, I'm looking for an integral with the original PDF in it, if it's possible to get a conditional expectation in that form. I'm guessing just restrict the limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the CDF is $G\left(x\right)=P\left(X\leq x\right)$ and the PDF is $g\left(x\right)=\frac{d}{dx}G\left(x\right)$ then the conditional expectation is $$E\left[X|X<a\right]=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{a}u\cdot g\left(u\right)du}{\int_{-\infty}^{a}g\left(u\right)du}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{a}u\cdot g\left(u\right)du}{G\left(a\right)}$$